# Why I can bind lvalue to universal references only when it has template deduction?

Tags: c++

I'm reading **Scott Meyers - Effective Modern C++** and even though I understand **when** I can and cannot bind lvalue references to universal references, I cannot understand the **reasons** behind this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A{
public:
    A(std::string && s){}
};

class B{
public:
    template<typename T>
    B(T&& t){}
};

int main()
{
    std::string t;
    //A a(t); //won't compile
    B b(t); //compiles

    return 0;
}
```

I don't see any undefined behaviour in passing `t`, which is an lvalue reference to `A()` so it gets bound as `std::string &`. Why simply having type deduction make it possible?

Comment: `std::string&&` is r value reference, **not** universe reference.

Comment: Try also reading [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) by Scott Meyers.

Comment: BTW: The official term nowadays is FORWARDING reference ! (universal reference is a misnomer)

Comment: @engf-010 unfortunately one can still find lots of articles (also from Scott) that call them universal, which can be rather confusing

Comment: @formerly: that does not take away the fact that we must use the correct terms. (from now and in the future).

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not a forwarding (universal) reference. It is an **rvalue** reference, and rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in `B` the template parameter `T` is itself allowed to be a reference type. In your example, I believe the compiler is inferring `T` to be of type `std::string&`, which means that after monomorphisation, the constructor of `B` will have a signature `B(std::string& && t)`. Then, [reference collapsing](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlcpp1313.aix.doc/language_ref/reference_collapsing.html) rules take over, which converts `std::string& &&` to `std::string&` (if you like, you can think: "an r-value reference to an l-value reference is an l-value reference"). This matches the type you are attempting to invoke the constructor with.

`A`, on the other hand, insists on being given a `std::string&&`, which you don't have, so the compiler rejects it. The compiler *must* reject it, because the assumption is that when a value is passed by r-value reference (`&&`), then it effectively isn't accessible from any other scope. Many function implementations rely on this assumption to allow them to efficiently reusue the internal memory representation of the passed value, rather than making copies, safe in the knowledge that nothing else is relying on it (think of move semantics and `std::swap`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between *forwarding (universal) reference* and rvalue reference.You have rvalue reference in your example. Scott Mayers should explain it in details in *Effective Modern C++*.
The main feature of forwarding references is that compiler may determine whether it's rvalue or lvalue. Read more about reference collapsing. [Here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) is a good reference to start. Also Mayers should write about it in *Effective Modern C++*.

Comment: @engf-010 The question is about *why only template*, and the answer is *reference collapsing*. Or I misunderstood something? Universal reference is just Mayer's name, I know :) But I got used to that naming

Comment: the thinng formerly known as universal reference has since c++17 an official name : forwarding reference (which describes exactly what is taking place) ,there is nothing universal about them (wrong confusing name).